# Polly Bulkhead unexpected behavior when using in ASP.NET Core

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dotnet-httpclient, polly

This is my bulkhead policy:

```
BulkheadPolicy = Policy
    .BulkheadAsync(maxParallelization: 2,
        maxQueuingActions: 2, onBulkheadRejectedAsync: (context) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Rejected");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });
```

It should allow only 4 concurrent tasks to execute/wait for execution.
However, I end up getting 6 tasks being able to run through the bulkhead policy.

This is my controller action:

```
[HttpGet("bulkhead")]
public async Task<object> Bulkhead()
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow);

    var bhCount = _policyManager.BulkheadPolicy.BulkheadAvailableCount;
    var queueCount = _policyManager.BulkheadPolicy.QueueAvailableCount;

    // The policy is used here
    await _policyManager.BulkheadPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async (context) =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(10000);
    }, new Context());

    return new
    {
        bhCount,
        queueCount
    };
}
```

In my browser, I used this script to simulate 14 concurrent tasks:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    fetch('https://localhost:44313/api/Bulkheads/bulkhead')
        .then(result=>console.log(result));
}
```

which should produce only 4 `200OK` responses. However, I end up getting 6 `200OK` responses.
I ran the test many times and got the same result. Does anybody have an idea why since the same behavior works well with a console application? Did I miss something here? Many thanks.

**UPDATE 1**:
This is my `IPolicyManager` interface

```
    public interface IPolicyManager
    {
        AsyncBulkheadPolicy BulkheadPolicy { get; }
    }

    public class PolicyManager : IPolicyManager
    {
        public PolicyManager()
        {
             Init();
        }

        public AsyncBulkheadPolicy BulkheadPolicy { get; private set; }

        private void Init()
        {
            BulkheadPolicy = Policy
                .BulkheadAsync(maxParallelization: 2,
                    maxQueuingActions: 2, onBulkheadRejectedAsync: (context) =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Rejected");
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    });
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE 2**:
When I send a fixed request (fixed URL), it failed quite slow, but when I append a random argument in the requests, the result is as expected (fail fast and only 4 requests can proceed).

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    fetch('https://localhost:44313/api/Bulkheads/bulkhead?count=' + i)
        .then(result=>console.log(result));
}
```

Comment: Can you please share with us the `_policyManager`'s related code as well? My best guess is that you are using more than 1 bulkhead policy during the API calls. Because each and every `/api/Bulkheads/bulkhead` call will create a new controller instance.

Comment: Hi @PeterCsala, I registered `services.AddSingleton<IPolicyManager, PolicyManager>();` in the Startup.cs file. The service is just a container of policies and it creates those policies only once for reuse throughout the project.

Comment: Can you please share with us the `IPolicyManager` interface?  Have you defined the `BulkheadPolicy` as property?

Comment: Alright, I updated the question above.

Comment: This seems good. Then my next guess is that you are using a wrong overload of the  `ExecuteAsync`. Because the Context is unused then you can call it without that `ExecuteAsync(async () => await Task.Delay(10000));` Could you please check it?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it didn't work. However, I just came up with a new experiment. When I send a fixed request (fixed URL), it failed quite slow, but when I append a random argument in the requests, the result is as expected (fail fast and only 4 requests can proceed). Maybe we are dealing with ASP.NET Core or browser caching or something?
`
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    fetch('https://localhost:44313/api/Bulkheads/bulkhead?count='+i)
        .then(result=>console.log(result));
}
`

Comment: You can exclude the browser by calling your API from a simple console application via `HttpClient`. You can use that to confirm your theory.

Comment: I'm glad that it works as expected. :D Please mark your own post as the answer to close this topic.

Comment: Many thanks, @PeterCsala. The site says that I will be able to mark it as the answer tomorrow so I will come back later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the browser's behavior was not as expected. I wrote a console application that does the same task and it works well: fail fast and only 4 requests can proceed at a time.
So I can confirm this is not an issue from Polly or ASP.NET Core.
Maybe it relates to caching mechanism of web browser (I'm using Edge): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching